# Advantage of using "IF Amplifier" over traditional OP amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, low-noise-amplifier

I am trying to receive 1MHz ultrasonic signal with transducer.

So, I will need to design some kind of filter to only pass 1MHz signal and filter out other noise signals.

Searching online for OP amp configuration, I found something called "IF Amplifier".

Below is the link to datasheet.
[[MC1350] - IF amplifier(Datasheet)](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwic4OOYzozLAhXHX5QKHbgeCgUQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.radiovilag.hu%2Fimages%2FMC1350.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHGHhiGA7azA5yc9rlf6iAYOQJK5A&sig2=1syOrY5KxaHfQIpzMgSAsQ&cad=rjt)

What is the advantage of using such specific IC over using generic OP amp with nice parameter(high input impedance and GBP, low offset voltage and output impedance)? In terms of noise performance, signal attenuation, jitter, and etc.

Comment: AGC for one thing. And "Power gain of 50dB at 45 MHz" translates to a pretty big GBW product (even though it doesn't imply 50dB voltage gain). Lastly, this thing came out when opamps struggled to reach 1 MHz. Modern opamps will be a bit more competitive with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one is implementing a notch-filter or a narrow band-pass filter, for noise performance, better use in differential mode and with dual power supply.

If this filtered output is not driving any output, we don't need high current sourcing capability.

May be something like LT1028 would suffice. (With least THD and noise levels, it may be useful to end application. http://www.linear.com/product/LT1007)